# How do you render previously selected option in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Currently I have a select tag with various options for the State in a from that I have.  When validations fail, the page is rendered again and the previously entered values in the textboxes don't get lost and are still present.  But the selected items aren't retained.  How do I code it so it is retained?

View code:

```
= form_for @user do |f|
  = f.text_field :name
  = f.select :state, { "California" => "CA", "Texas" => "TX"} , :prompt => ''
  = f.submit "Submit"
```

Controller code:

```
 def new
   @user = User.new
 end

 def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can we see the "create" action?

Comment: Is your form for 'new' and 'create' is the same as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your controller code is good. Your view code is likely the culprit here. Please make sure the forms in your view are consistent.